# How to call two functions onClick in React when one of the uses properties from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that I am sorted and I would like to change the css class of the arrow to indicate the current sorting. I have functions for both changing the class and also sorting the array but I cannot combine them onClick because one cannot be written exclusively as a functions. How can I combine these? Here is the relevant code:

The component

```
var Clickable = React.createClass ({

handleClick: function() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.index);
},

render: function () {
    return <img className={this.props.isActive ? 'currentArrow' : 'arrow'}      onClick={this.handleClick}
                src={this.props.src} />
}
});
```

The container

```
  var LeaderBoard = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    this.state = {
        activeIndex: null
    };
    return {
        data: loading,
    };
},

handleClick: function(index) {
    this.setState({activeIndex: index});
},

componentWillMount: function() {
    fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent', {
        method: 'get'
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        this.setState({
            data: data,
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error is ", error);
    });
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="Title" className="row">
                <h1>freeCodeCamp Leaderboard</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                    <h4>#</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <h4>Camper Name
                        <Clickable index={0} isActive={this.state.activeIndex===0}
 ////Second function works but the class is not changed
                        onClick={() => {this.handleClick; this.setState(this.state.data.sort(sortDescending("recent")))}}
                        src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png"/>
                        <Clickable index={1} isActive={this.state.activeIndex===1}
  ///class is changed but I cannot add the sorting function
                        onClick ={this.handleClick}
                        src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png"/>
                    </h4>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div>{information}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

});


ReactDOM.render(<LeaderBoard />, document.getElementById('theBoard'));
```

I realized its a lot of code but I tried to take out the part that's not pertinent.

Comment: why don't you just update the state on onClick handler itself rather than calling a separate method?

Comment: Thats what I did originally but I have six different arrows and I need a different sort function for each one, so a broad onClick handler wouldn't work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: There's a bug in your code...
onClick={() => {this.handleClick; this.setState(this.state.data.sort(sortDescending("recent")))}}

you need to do this.handleClick() here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a prop to each child that represents how that particular arrow sorts data, and then use that in the handleclick method to sort data conditionally.

Parent:

```
var LeaderBoard = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        this.state = {
            activeIndex: null
        };
        return {
            data: 'loading',
        };
    },

    handleClick: function(sortType, index) {
        const sortedData = this.state.data.slice();

        if (sortType.direction === "descending") {
            sortedData.sort(sortDescending(sortType.filter));
        }
        // other sortTypes here

        this.setState({
            activeIndex: index,
            data: sortedData
        });
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
        fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent', {
            method: 'get'
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            this.setState({
                data: data,
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("error is ", error);
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="Title" className="row">
                    <h1>freeCodeCamp Leaderboard</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <h4>#</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <h4>Camper Name
                            <Clickable index={0} 
                              isActive={this.state.activeIndex===0}
                              onClick={(sortType, index) => this.handleClick(sortType, index)}
                              sortType = {{direction: 'ascending', filter: 'recent'}}
                              src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png"
                            />
                            <Clickable index={0} 
                              isActive={this.state.activeIndex===0}
                              onClick={(sortType, index) => this.handleClick(sortType, index)}
                              sortType = {{direction: 'descending', filter: 'recent'}}
                              src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png"
                            />
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>{information}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Child:

```
var Clickable = React.createClass ({

    handleClick: function() {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.sortType, this.props.index);
    },

    render: function () {
        return <img className={this.props.isActive ? 'currentArrow' : 'arrow'}      onClick={this.handleClick}
                    src={this.props.src} />
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in this line sortData = {direction: 'ascending', filter: 'recent'} but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I missed a set of curly brackets - one is needed for using JS inside JSX, the other pair for object literal notation. I've edited my answer.

Comment: In that same line, sortData also needs to be SortType but it appears to be working. Thank you, this is originally want I wanted to do but I couldn't figure out how to do it and I didn't realize I wasn't using React correctly in the other.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by passing the data to the child and using and if statement in the handeClick based on the index to execute the appropriate function.

Parent:

```
<Clickable data={this.state.data} index={0} isActive={this.state.activeIndex===0} onClick={this.handleClick}

src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png"/>
```

Child:

```
var Clickable = React.createClass ({

handleClick: function() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.index);
    if (this.props.index ===0) {
        this.setState(this.props.data.sort(sortAscending("username")));
    }
    else if (this.props.index ===1) {
        this.setState(this.props.data.sort(sortDescending("username")));
    }
    else if (this.props.index ===2) {
        this.setState(this.props.data.sort(sortAscending("recent")));
    }
    else if (this.props.index ===3) {
        this.setState(this.props.data.sort(sortDescending("recent")));
    }
    else if (this.props.index ===4) {
        this.setState(this.props.data.sort(sortAscending("alltime")));
    }
    else if (this.props.index ===5) {
        this.setState(this.props.data.sort(sortDescending("alltime")));
    }
},

render: function () {
    return <img className={this.props.isActive ? 'currentArrow' : 'arrow'} onClick={this.handleClick}
                src={this.props.src} />
}
});
```

Comment: The state you are accessing and modifying in your Clickable component is not the same state as in the parent component, so your handleClick function will appear to do nothing.  What it will actually do is duplicate the parent's state into the child component, which is diametrically opposite to what is typically desirable in a React app.  This approach is also extremely inflexible - we are tightly coupling the index of a component to its behaviour when clicked.

Comment: It also has the [common React anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/1816/state-in-react/15854/common-antipattern#t=201612121755553628917) of deriving state from props.

Comment: I made the comments because what you posted above won't work, and if you use React in this way it will cause you major problems in the future.  If you don't want help and advice to improve  then SO is probably the wrong place to be.